# How to perform Hsqldb SET Operation dynamically in Spring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, hsqldb, h2, spring-jdbc

We are using **HSQL Database Engine 2.3.2** with `Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE` while my spring configuration is as following:

Here is `applicationContext.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <bean class="com.chorke.spring.bootstarp.HyperSqlDbServer" id="hsqldb" init-method="start">
        <constructor-arg>
            <props>
                <prop key="server.port">9002</prop>
                <prop key="server.dbname.0">chorke</prop>
                <prop key="server.remote_open">true</prop>
                <prop key="server.database.0">file:~/.hsqldb/chorke/data;sql.syntax_mys=true;user=admin;password=pa55word</prop>
                <prop key="hsqldb.default_table_type">text</prop>
                <prop key="hsqldb.reconfig_logging">false</prop>
            </props>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9002/chorke" />
        <property name="username" value="admin" />
        <property name="password" value="pa55word" />
    </bean>

    <jdbc:initialize-database  data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

Here is `com.chorke.spring.bootstarp.HyperSqlDbServer`

```
package com.chorke.spring.bootstarp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.hsqldb.Server;
import org.hsqldb.persist.HsqlProperties;
import org.hsqldb.server.ServerAcl.AclFormatException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle;

public class HyperSqlDbServer implements SmartLifecycle {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HyperSqlDbServer.class);
    private HsqlProperties properties;
    private Server server;
    private boolean running = false;

    public HyperSqlDbServer(Properties props) {
        properties = new HsqlProperties(props);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        if (server != null)
            server.checkRunning(running);
        return running;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (server == null) {
            logger.info("Starting HSQL server...");
            server = new Server();
            try {
                server.setProperties(properties);
                server.start();
                running = true;
            } catch (AclFormatException afe) {
                logger.error("Error starting HSQL server.", afe);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error starting HSQL server.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        logger.info("Stopping HSQL server...");
        if (server != null) {
            server.stop();
            running = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable runnable) {
        stop();
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Here is `schema.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t001i001(pf_id INTEGER,df_name VARCHAR(20));
--SET TABLE t001i001 SOURCE 't001i001.csv;fs=|;vs=.';
```

Here is `data.sql`

```
insert into t001i001(pf_id, df_name) values(1, 'Shefat Hossain');
```

Where I want to add some script to perform some `SET` operation dynamically as like as what was commented in `schema.sql` on second line. using spring.

---

Any way to perform `SET` operation logically/dynamically inside Spring Application Context?

Answer (score 1):

Here is wrong assumption of me as As I declared the property at `applicationContext.xml` on `hsqldb` bean as below:

```xml
<prop key="hsqldb.default_table_type">text</prop>
```

It's suppose to me that it would be help us to defaulting database table engine `TEXT` instead of `MEMORY`. As the table default engine was `MEMORY` so the 2nd line of `schema.sql` not executing. after editing `schema.sql` it working fine, no problem on `SET` operation as following:

```
CREATE TEXT TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t001i001(pf_id INTEGER,df_name VARCHAR(20));
SET TABLE t001i001 SOURCE 't001i001.csv;fs=|;vs=.';
```